# What happens if Australian Permanent Resident tries to return with no RRV?

Tags: visas, australian-residents

I have been an Australian Permanent Resident for 7 years. This means I am allowed to remain in the country till I die, with complete rights to work, government assistance, etc. Yet I don't have the right to re-enter the country after a trip abroad. This seems like a weird situation.

I'm curious: What happens if I turn up at Australian Immigration without the required Residents Return Visa?

(I am approved for citizenship, but I am not a citizen because I am still waiting for a pledge ceremony)

Comment: As I understand it they expect permanent residents to apply for citizenship as soon as they are eligible (after 4 years, before your [5 year travel facility](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/permanent-resident/overseas-travel) expires.).

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think many could be waiting >1 year just for their citizenship ceremony in the current circumstances... though there has been talk of a move to online ceremonies.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't think there is any such expectation, and I know people who have been in Australia for >10 years as PR, typically because their country doesn't allow dual citizenship.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will not be able to turn up at Australian immigration, because your documentation will be checked by the airline first, and you will be denied boarding for lack of a valid Australian visa.

However, as an Australian PR, [you can apply for a new RRV](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/permanent-resident/overseas-travel) even if your previous one has expired.  [You will need to demonstrate](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/resident-return-visa-155-157#Eligibility) that you've been in Australia for at least 2 of the last 5 years, or that you have other "substantial ties to Australia that are of benefit to Australia".

Comment: I think that instead of "entry" in the second line, it'd be clearer to use the words "boarding the flight to Australia."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Good point, updated.